# How to Import different versions of my Maven Project in IntelliJ with Different Project Names

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having the following Maven Projects which have the same Project Name but with different versions.

> 1)ArtifactId=Processor, version=5.10.0.0000
>
> 2)ArtifactId=Processor, version=5.9.0.0000
>
> 3)ArtifactId=Processor, version=5.8.0.0000

When I import these Projects in intelliJ , I am getting 'Processor' as project name. So I have 3 'Processor' projects with the same name. At times its really confusing, currently I am distinguishing each project using their File Path. Is there any way I can change the project Name without changing the name in `pom.xml` to distinguish each project.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the root folder in IntelliJ and choose `refactor -> rename`, it should change the project name.

Comment: I have already renamed using Refractor->Rename ,Now i have closed all the Projects, but even then once i am trying to open the project ,i am able to see the Options as Processor,Processor,Processor.So still it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

File | Project Structure | Project | **Project name:** - change it.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, this is not a good practice because when classloader load 3 projects (when you run it into server) only one are loaded and you can have ClassNotFoundException error because not exists other two in classpath.

You should have everything you need in the latest version. If not, you can change the name of the packages in each version, but this does not seem to be a good practice.